# RelativeSource binding works from Style but not ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

An entry in my `Application.Resources` `ResourceDictionary` is a control template that, slimmed down, looks similar to the following:

```cs
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border>
        <Border.BorderBrush>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=BorderColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}" />
        </Border.BorderBrush>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Each `UserControl` has its own property `BorderColor` which this pulls from. In this example, the binding fails to find the property.

> Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource
>   FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.UserControl',
>   AncestorLevel='1''.

However, it works in another entry in the dictionary:

```cs
<Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{Binding Path=BorderColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}"/>
</Style>
```

How can I fix the binding in the first example? Preferably I would like to not need additional properties on the instance of each control in the user control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

If the ControlTemplate is part of a Style you could set the `BorderBrush` property of the ToggleButton to the `SolidColorBrush` with the binding and use a `TemplateBinding` in the template:

```
<Style x:Key="myStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
        <Setter.Value>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=BorderColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="10">
                    <TextBlock>....</TextBlock>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you want to define a standalone ControlTemplate for some reason a workaround would be to bind to a Brush property instead of a Color property:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Path=BorderBrushProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" BorderThickness="10">
        <TextBlock>....</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I did some rejigging of the template to make it into a `Style` as in the first example. Using the `TemplateBinding` then worked, thanks! Now to make it update dynamically...

Comment: If I want to set some text on textblock using the same approach then what can I do?

Answer (score -1):

It works if you use Background instead of BorderColor. Is BorderColor your own property?

```
<Window.Resources>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="template" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Border>
        <Border.BorderBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
        </Border.BorderBrush>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<UserControl Background="Aqua">
    <ToggleButton Template="{StaticResource template}"></ToggleButton>

</UserControl>
```